# How to override module-ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html in Magento2

Tags: magento2, template-override

In Magento2, how to override the following template?

> /vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html

I found the answer [Better Checkout Error Message Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196862/better-checkout-error-message-magento-2)
and I copied it to the following place like the answer suggests:

> /app/design/frontend/[YourPackage]/default/Magento_Ui/web/template/messages.html

but it is not overridden.

But the following another template under module-theme can be overridden by copying it to the following location.

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml

to

> /app/design/frontend/[YourPackage]/default/Magento_Theme/templates/messages.phtml

I also executed the following command but nothing changed:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did perfectly.

just make sure there are no any 3rd party or cloudfare cache applied on your website.

If applied then please do flush/purge it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have much knowledge about our magento2 project or magento2 itself. But I have to quickly modify the file. 
Maybe something is cached or the file is not the file I'm trying to modify. Which directory or files or configs should I check to check if something is cached?
And, is there an easy way to identify the files which are used in a specific page?

Comment: Please run ``php bin/magento cache:flush`` and check in private window.

Comment: thank you. cache:flush was already executed. it seems i'm overriding a wrong template. i gave up overriding or finding it. but it was very helpful to know that i did perfectly.